# Excel Sumproduct/Sumif based on multiple criteria across two tables not in order

Tags: excel

I've been struggling with an issue for a while now and haven't been able to find a solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to build a formula that sums up values from a column based on criteria spread across two tables (I've simplified below):

**Table 1**

```
+-------------+---------+---------------------+------------+----------+------+
| Customer ID | Twin ID | Customer Entry Date | Exit Date  | Spending | Days |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+------------+----------+------+
|         111 |     333 |          24.12.2015 | 28.05.2018 |     5000 |  200 |
|         222 |     444 |          19.06.2014 |            |     4000 |  300 |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+------------+----------+------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+-------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+----------+------+
| Customer ID | Twin ID | Customer Entry Date | Exit Date | Spending | Days |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+----------+------+
|         444 |         |                     |           |          |  200 |
|         333 |         |                     |           |          |    0 |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+----------+------+
```

I now need to find a formula, that will allow me to sum up the column "Spending" from table 1 based on the following criteria:

- "Twin ID" in Table 1 is not empty and the value matches the value "Customer ID" in Table 2 --> this has been the main complication for me, as the Customer IDs in Table 2 are in a different order than the Twin IDs in Table 1
- "Entry Date" in Table 1 is < a specific date
- "Exit Date" in Table 1 is >= a specific date or empty
- "Days" in Table 2 is >0 (for the respective Customer ID that matches the Twin ID from Table 1)

Or in other words: "If customers 111,222 etc. have a twin, and this twin has days >0, and the entry and exit dates of the customer are < > a specific date or empty, then sum up the spending of those customers"

I've tried various iterations of the SUMPRODUCT formula, and this one currently works as long as the two tables are in the same order (i. e. Twin ID "333" is in row 2 in Table 1 and in row 2 in Table 2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1!Customer Entry Date<DATE1);--(Table1!Exit Date>=Date2);--(Table1!TwinID<>"");--(Table2!Days>0);Table1!Spending)
```

Is there any way to make this formula work regardless of the order of the row items (i. e. Twin ID "333" is in row 2 in Table 1 and in row 3 in Table 2)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have Table1 and V1_Table1 worksheets in your formula ?

Comment: My mistake, i simplified the names of the tables and forgot to take that V1_ out. Edited it out just now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1!Customer_Entry_Date<Date1)*(Table1!Customer_Entry_Date>Date2)*(Table1!Twin_ID<>"")*(COUNTIFS(Table2!Customer_ID,Table1!Twin_ID,Table2!Days,">0")>0)*Table1!Spending)
```

It's similar to your formula, but uses Countifs to see if a matching Customer ID for Table 1's Twin ID is anywhere in table 2.

Note that your named ranges (if that's what you're using) should not include the column headers or else you'll get a #Value error when it tries to do the multiplication.

You could avoid it by putting IF(Isnumber()) around the last part of the bracket, but then it would have to be entered as an array formula

```
=SUM((Table1!Customer_Entry_Date<Date1)*(Table1!Customer_Entry_Date>Date2)*(Table1!Twin_ID<>"")*(COUNTIFS(Table2!Customer_ID,Table1!Twin_ID,Table2!Days,">0")>0)*IF(ISNUMBER(Table1!Spending),Table1!Spending))
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately this doesn't do the trick either. I've used the Evaluate Formula function to narrow down the core problem at hand: as per my understanding, the arrays within the Sumproduct function generate Boolean outputs in a specific order. Due to the fact that the function references conditions from two tables that are not sorted in the same way, the generated {TRUE;FALSE} statements are not matched correctly and thus the result will always be off. i have yet to find a way to make sure the values are all correctly matched up by the formula ...

Comment: Right, I see. Can you be more specific plz and say first of all whether you get the answer you're expecting from your example - I get 4000 because the second row in table 1 matches with the row in table 2 that has 200 days.

Comment: You are right that it will give the wrong answer if there is more than one matching twin - I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Hi Tom, I've created an example file to reflect the issue:
[link]https://wetransfer.com/downloads/445248f21042b22bcf5851e1cd96aa6520180628180436/fbb473

Comment: Going out now but will try and have a look later

Comment: Managed to solve it in the meantime, thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue.

Anyone facing a similar problem, please see the example file for solution: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/90aedc5943f52274e36102a79e23c18e20180628212338/2fd1c1

```
=+SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Table1TwinID;Table2CustomerID;Table1Spending)*(Table2Days>0)*((COUNTIFS(Table1TwinID;Table2CustomerID;Table1EntryDate;"<"&DATE1)*COUNTIFS(Table1TwinID;Table2CustomerID;Table1ExitDate;">="&DATE2))+(COUNTIFS(Table1TwinID;Table2CustomerID;Table1EntryDate;"<"&DATE1)*COUNTIFS(Table1TwinID;Table2CustomerID;Table1ExitDate;""))))
```